# Jython interactive shell from breakpoint

Tags: debugging, jython, ipdb

Usually when I'm working in Python, my favourite go to tool is dropping into a piece of code using `ipdb.set_trace()` and starting an interactive shell. Is there any way to do this with Jython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdb` still works in Jython since it's part of the standard library. So you can still execute `pdb.set_trace()`. You'll just have to deal with living without the glorious features of `iPython`.